# Cannot resolve error:- Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory failed to initialize KVM: No such file or directory

Tags: kernel, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to do RIFT's standalone installation on Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox but each time I run the Launchpad file it is throwing this error. My **bios virtualization** is also enabled and QEMU KVM is also installed.

My Launchpad file looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
brctl addbr br0
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 promisc
brctl addif br0 eth0
dhclient br0
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 3072 -enable-kvm rift-ui-latest.qcow2 -net nic,vlan=0 -net tap,vlan=0,ifname=tap0,script=./Tap_Bridge_Setup -nographic
```

`rift-it-latest.qcow2` is the rift image which I am trying to install. How can I install it?

Comment: What's your CPU (`lscpu`)? What happen if you run `modprobe kvm-intel` or `modprobe kvm-amd` (depending on the vendor of the CPU) as root?

Comment: @TomYan   After running command :- modprobe kvm-intel 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'kvm_intel': Operation not supported

Comment: By "as root" @TomYan means with `sudo`. Did you run the commands with sudo? If not please try again.

Comment: Virtual Box already have problem with nested virtualization . try `egrep 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo` for if your CPU support virtualization or not .Also if it supported try @TomYan way to check if module loaded or not .

Comment: @MichaelBay i m in root user itself. still its is not showing anything.

Comment: @AliGhasempour egrep 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo command is not showing any output . But when i run dmesg command it is showing [ [1481.744004] kvm: no hardware support
[ 2865.319385] kvm: no hardware support
[ 2906.511195] kvm: no hardware support

Comment: @RashmiAglawe As I said there is problem with nested virtualization on virtual box so there is no cpu feature for your Ubuntu guest . You can use VMWARE virtualization or setup kvm on host . They support nested virtualization .

Comment: @AliGhasempour isnt there any other way to enable kvm in my ubuntu vm  and get it running ?

Comment: @AliGhasempour the OP didn't mention anything on "nested" though? She only mentioned that "qemu kvm" is installed (my guess is she thought that qemu needs to be installed for virtualbox virtualization to work).

Comment: I wonder if it's just the CPU not supporting VT-x or so. Again, what's the full model of the CPU, as shown in `lscpu`?

Comment: @RashmiAglawe Try VMWARE workstation for virtualization . KVM need to be supportet by cpu virtualization feature .

Comment: @TomYan lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               3292.534
BogoMIPS:              6585.06
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full